# MySQL Database store image url and php page display it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I was wondering if there’s any way I could store an image URL in a database with a unique numeric id, and a php page display the image by getting data (the image URL) from the database and displaying it to the user on the image.php page?

An example of this would be:
- Having the image URL http://www.example.com/images/image10.jpg (where this URL would be stored in the database, alongside an id of 10)
- Having an image.php page which retrieves the image URL from the database and displays the image on the same page (the image.php page) (and doesn’t redirect to the image URL) - an example result being image.php?id=10 where the image.php file would source the image URL from the database with an image id of 10  (using my example: www.example.com/images/image10.jpg) and display it (so it would be like viewing the image as if you were viewing www.example.com/images/image10.jpg but instead the URL would be http://www.example.com/image.php?id=10)

Is there any way to do this?
I'm new to php and MySQL so not really good with code - trying to experiment :)

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I think people are getting confused by my bad description (sorry abot that).
I've noticed in your answers that you have included the actual image URL in your code - I dont understand why though.

EXAMPLE of how I'd like this to work:

My table would have these feilds:
img_id
img_url

The image.php file would GET the img_url FROM the table using the id on the end of the image.php url. FOR EXAMPLE:
- image.php?id=10 - the image.php file would use the id (which is 10), and display the image by retreiving the img_url (which would be: www.example.com/images/image10.jpg) from the table and displaying it - the image id would be img_id in the table. 
- image.php?id=12 - the image.php file would use the id (which is 12) and display the image by retreiving the img_url (which would be: www.example.com/images/image12.jpg) from the table and displaying it - the image id would be img_id in the table.

Comment: Can you give us some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
//File: image.php?id=10 
//you query   
$img = 'http://example.com/sample.jpg'; // Image path from database
$getInfo = getimagesize($img);
header('Content-type: ' . $getInfo['mime']);
readfile($img);
```

Comment: This looks good but I'm confused by your answer - I want the php code to Source the image URL from the database, then display an image based on its ID - for example Image10.jpg would have a unique numeric id in the database - this being 10. So I want the image.php to Display AN image by first getting the id (like: image.php?id=10) and using the image url to display the image - where the image url would be on the same row (or would be part of the same record) as the record with an id '10'.

Comment: Your comment is not clear to me. please explain in simpler way, so may be I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this :

`$image_path="http://example.com/image10.jpg";'
'mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('',$image_path)");`

in the php have this :

`$id=$_GET['id'];if (isset($_GET['id'])){'
'$result = mysql_query("SELECT path FROM table WHERE id=$id");'
'$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);'
'$path=$row[0];echo "Image number ".$id." is <img src='".$path."'>';}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am confused by this though - why would the image url be in this php code if the php file has to GET the image URL from the database?

Comment: You said you want the link look like this : http://www.example.com/image.php?id=10 . This means that you want to send the id through the link. The php takes the id from the link with $_GET['id']. Then searches within the database for the image with this id. When it founds it it takes the path. If all images look like this : image 10 image 11 etc you can use $path='http://www.example.com/image.php?id='; $path.=$_GET['id']; $path.='.jpg'; This code will results http://www.example.com/image.php?id=10 . With ".=" you concatenate strings.

Comment: Mysql injections would work here very easy, also use mysqli_* functions the mysql_* are marked as deprecated

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your code organisation, let me explain my self, right now in my mind i can think of two ways of organisation:

First, using a folder containing all images, with the same name + number for each image; e.g: images/img1.jpg - images/img2.jpg - images/img3.jpg etc

Using this method you'll not have to use even database, just within your page you go for this code, exemple for page http://exemple.com/images.php?id=10

```
$id = (isset($_GET["id"]))? $_GET["id"] : NULL; //Get the ID
```

Then use the method given by user3410107

```
$img = "http://example.com/img$id.jpg"; // Image path
$getInfo = getimagesize($img);
header('Content-type: ' . $getInfo['mime']);
readfile($img);
```

Second method is indeed using database, in this case there should be at least 2 columns within db, a unique ID + Images path, in this case you'll go for:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, imagePath FROM table WHERE id = $id");
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$img = $data["imagePath"];
}
```

Once you get the image path, the same process as before:

```
$getInfo = getimagesize($img);
header('Content-type: ' . $getInfo['mime']);
readfile($img);
```

For security reasons add this line after $id variable

```
$id = (isset($_GET["id"]))? $_GET["id"] : NULL; //Get the ID
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

Comment: Please use the mysqli_* functions, mysql_* is marked as deprecated

Comment: Thanks! The second method is the method I wanted!